# Does a contract deployment always use the same amount of gas regardless of network conditions?

Tags: gas

Does the deployment of a contract always uses the same amount of gas to deploy on the Ethereum mainnet, regardless of network conditions?

I understand that `gas` and `gas price` are two different things, so the final cost of deployment can vary greatly when the cost of gas changes. However, this question is about **the amount of gas used**.

If I deploy a smart contract when network congestion is low, and then again when network congestion is high, is the same `amount` of gas always used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the deployment (constructor) doesn't depend on other contracts (or do something other really weird stuff, like do different things based on the current block number) then yes - the used gas amount should always be the same.

This may vary slightly based on the *network*, since other EVM networks may have different gas prices for different operations. I don't think this happens much yet (except zkEVMs), but might happen more in future networks. But at least within one network the price should stay the same.